# Exclude parameter in du command

Tags: command-line, grep, regular-expression, io-redirection, disk-usage

I found somehow interesting command do specify disk usage which I am using without actually knowing what does the exclude pattern do. Instead excluding some locations or file names or just globs, the exclude pattern consists of the regular expression `'*[0-9]G*'`

Complete command is  `du --exclude='*[0-9]G*' -hax / | grep '[0-9]G\>'` but the first exclude parameter and the last grep parameter are a little bit confusing me as I thought on the first that I am excluding the exactly same parameter whih I am grepping later.  Any help with these arguments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'*[0-9]G*'` is in fact a glob expression - not a regular expression.

The command excludes *input filenames* matching `'*[0-9]G*'`, and then greps for `du` *output lines* matching `'[0-9]G\>'` such as would be produced due to the `-h` (`--human-readable`) `du` option - for example

```
3.3G  /usr/lib
```

Comment: Basically, the exclude glob expression will exclude the filenames with the numerical characters in file name and the 'G' acts as a switch for the global search? And the grep will filter just results with the file size larger than 1GB also? I know that the [0-9] is range, but what 'G\>' stands for?

Comment: Almost - the `G` is literal in both the `du` glob expression and the `grep` regex. The `\>` in the `grep` regex is a GNU-specific [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)